# Can't resolve component import VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use `MainNavbarButton` within `MainNavbar`. I imported the component, but get the error of `"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/MainNavbarButton.vue'"` All the solutions I found seem to stem from a spelling mistake, but I'm pretty sure that's not the case here.

MainNavbar.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="navbar">
    <MainNavbarButton />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MainNavbarButton from './components/MainNavbarButton.vue'
export default {
  name: 'MainNavbar',
  components: {
    MainNavbarButton
  }
}
</script>
```

MainNavbarButton.vue

```
<template>
  <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MainNavbarButton',
  props: {
    title
  }
};
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <MainNavbar/>
</template>

<script>
import MainNavbar from './components/MainNavbar.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    MainNavbar
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are both MainNavbarButton.vue and MainNavbar.vue in the components directory? If so you import should be `import MainNavbarButton from './MainNavbarButton.vue'`

Comment: @JasonWhite Yes, they're both in the components directory.

Comment: The import path is wrong then,  remove the`components` from the import path